# Attaching an object to _User object when _User is first created

Tags: parse-platform

I currently have a Facebook only login system. I want to attach a `PublicUser` object to my `_User` object, **only upon first creation of the _User**. I want to do this in my cloud code. As a precursor to my goal, I tried to come up with a quick way to see if `afterSave` is working:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
  var PublicUser = Parse.Object.extend("PublicUser");
  var publicUser = new PublicUser()
  publicUser.save();
});
```

However, no publicUser object was created. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, I checked it on my own project. Also check [this](https://parse.com/questions/add-user-to-to-a-role-via-after-save) thread about a similar question to see the same.

A few things you should check:

- Make sure the code is actually deployed. You can check that via Parse Control Panel -> Your App -> Core -> Cloud code. Make sure the code is actually there. Sometimes (especially if your developing using "`parse develop`") cli command, you will not see compilation errors when parse is trying to upload files and fails.

  - Make sure your trigger is imported to `main.js` via `require()` command. So if you saved your trigger in 'cloud/triggers/user.js' you should require('cloud/triggers/user.js') to make Parse aware of this code.
  - Finally, you should definitely use the oldest debugging technique in the book, and place `console.log()` statements in there.  You can read console out via running [parse develop](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/rapid-cloud-code-development-with-parse-develop/) to check

Comment: Thanks for checking. Actually, about 30 minutes later, 5 of these objects popped up in the data browser. Weird. It was empty when I refreshed the page for several tries.